# What type of database is a data.frame?

Tags: database, r

I was wondering what type of database is a data.frame. If we take a look at this answer [at Quora](http://www.quora.com/Database-Systems/In-what-situations-should-one-use-a-given-database-over-another), we have a good guide of what type of databases there are. Roughly speaking, we have relational databases (which I guess is not the case of a Data.Frame) and noSQL databases (columnar, Key-value, Document Store and Graph).

So, my question is: What kind of database is a data.frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A data frame is a relation. Each row is a tuple, each column is an attribute. See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28database%29

however it is strictly ordered, so I imagine DB theory purists would insist there is also a hidden attribute that defines the ordering that R uses.

Comment: Yeah, theres a few things about data frames that break the pure relation model such as row names, ordering, and any other attributes tacked on. Now, are they ACID-compliant....

Comment: Are you asking if they're ACID-compliant or stating that they are?

Comment: Pre-empting further questions really! But maybe they won't be asked.

Answer (score 4):

A data frame isn't a database.  It's more like a single table in a relational database, or a single sheet in a spreadsheet.

In R terms, you can also think of it as a hybrid of a list and a matrix.  That is it's like a non-nested list where each element has the same length, and it's like a matrix where each column can contain a different type of atomic variable.

Comment: A table in a relational database is a 'relation'. Some people think the term 'relational' refers to doing things like foreign keys (ie relating one table to another), but its not. A data frame is a relation.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, in R a data frame is actually a list of vectors of equal length, that is used to store data such as tables. Each column of the data frame is one of the equal length vectors i.e. each element of the data frame list is a column of the table. They are useful because you can mix data types in each column, for example one column can have a number, the next column can have a factor, just like lists in R can have mixed data types. This is one of the reasons you would pick a data.frame over a matrix, which only allow one data type.